# Get All Row Values Given One Cell Is Selected QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, qtableview

I am using PyQt5. I have a QTableView as follows:

```
1 a1 b1 c1
2 a2 b2 c2
3 a3 b3 c3
```

I know how to get the item's text of the selected ones as a list.

But I need the full row of those selected items.

Imagine, c1 and b3 are selected. Now I am getting `[c1, b3]`, how ever what I need is a dict or a list of lists with:

```
selected = {1:[a1,b1,c1], 2:[a3,b3,c3]}
ór
selected = [[a1,b1,c1],[a3,b3,c3]}
```

The code I am using to get the [c1, b3] is as follows:

```
selection = self.pandasTV.selectionModel()
indexes = selection.selectedIndexes()
cells_data = []
for i, index in enumerate(indexes):
    cells_data.append(self.model.data(index))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to access the row siblings of the selected indexes.

```
selection = self.pandasTV.selectionModel()
indexes = selection.selectedRows()
cells_data = []
columns = range(self.model.columnCount())
for index in indexes:
    row = index.row()
    cells_data.append([index.sibling(row, c).data() for c in columns])
```

Note that, since Qt 5.11, you can use [`index.siblingAtColumn(c).data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#siblingAtColumn).